# Could a blade of a large grasslike plant stop the fall of an “ant man”?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

If a typical human were shrunk down to be 3cm tall weighing 2.5 grams (ignoring all problems that would cause), would the blade of the grasslike plant described below be able to stop its fall from 6 inches up?

The grass has a rough texture as shown below

[image: grass texture]
([image source](http://www.micronaut.ch/blades-of-steel/))

The blade of grass is at a 70 degree angle and measures 2 ft long and 1 ft wide curling in on the sides (so he doesn't slide off) and comes to a point on the end. He lands half way down.

Would it be possible for him to come to a complete stop before touching the ground?

Comment: What is the mass of the shrunk human?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Any ideas?

Comment: You could probably drop a ~[0.4g](https://www.google.com/search?q=%283cm+%2F+5.2ft%29%5E3+*+137+lbs+in+g) (that's *(3cm / average male height)³ x average male weight*, very back of the napkin style math) object onto large houseplant leaf to get a guess.

Comment: I was thinking more like 2.5 grams; 0.5 times the weight of a typical crayon

Comment: That could work, too. In general for scale models of 3D stuff the mass is (scale^3)*weight but I'm sure you can take some creative liberties with his weight, 2.5g seems totally imaginable, too. So drop a half a crayon on a plant. Btw, like the crayon, unless he was very agile, he runs a pretty significant risk of bouncing off or sliding off on the way down. But I suppose it's not uncommon to have people in fiction pull off some pretty physically amazing stunts.

Comment: @JasonC please read the question thoroughly, I think I have accounted for that

Comment: @JasonC Congratulations on proposing an experimental method to answer the question. The scaling should be by volume, assuming constant density, although the cube rule based on height is a good approximation, so your formula gives a very usable  answer. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Is he actively trying to stop himself? Spreadeagled trying to use friction?

Comment: @Kilisi he's unconscious.

Answer (score 7):

Take a hundred foot mine shaft, drop mouse down it and the mouse will land uninjured. A person sufferong a similar drop will break every bone in his body. An elephant will splash.

The smaller an animal gets the less a fall can hurt it. Terminal velocity for small things is just too slow. Assuming the humans muscles don't shatter his miniscule bones during normal movement a fall is not going to bother him at all, so he doesn't *need* the grass. Buts lets say he wants to use it anyway.

Grass is a pretty wide description as well, some grasses would stop him no problem other would not, just make it wider and more rigid if you don't think it will work. Something like zebra grass would work no problem.

Comment: Small edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

### No

70 degrees is a really steep angle. If your tiny man was conscious, there's a chance he could grab onto some protrusions and slow himself down. Unconscious, though, there's simply not enough to keep him *on* the leaf.

After 6 inches, he'll be moving at [about 1.73 m/s](https://www.angio.net/personal/climb/speed.html). I second @JasonC's experimental suggestion just to make sure, but that's fast enough I would expect him to hit the leaf, begin sliding down as the leaf bends under his weight, then the leaf springs back and throws him off.